# No views are displayed in ViewRepeater with activated respnsive

Tags: sapui5

I've created this view. If I activate responsive, nothing is displayed. If I deactivate responsive I see the rows. What can be the reason?

```
createContent : function(oController) {  

    var oTileTemplate = new sap.ui.commons.layout.HorizontalLayout("tileTemplate");  

    var oEmployeeDetailsTemplate = new sap.ui.commons.layout.VerticalLayout("employeeDetailsTemplate");  

    //Name  
    var oEmployeeNameText = new sap.ui.commons.TextView( {  
        text: {  
            parts: [  
                    { path: "title" },  
                    { path: "firstname" },  
                    { path: "lastname" }  
            ]  
        },  
    });  
    oEmployeeDetailsTemplate.addContent(oEmployeeNameText);  

    //Company  
    var oEmployeeCompanyText = new sap.ui.commons.TextView( {  
        text: "{company}",  
    });  
    oEmployeeDetailsTemplate.addContent(oEmployeeCompanyText);  

    //Plant  
    var oEmployeePlantText = new sap.ui.commons.TextView( {  
        text: "{plant}",  
    });  
    oEmployeeDetailsTemplate.addContent(oEmployeePlantText);  

    //Orgunit  
    var oEmployeeOrgunitText = new sap.ui.commons.TextView( {  
        text: "{orgunit}",  
    });  
    oEmployeeDetailsTemplate.addContent(oEmployeeOrgunitText);  

    oTileTemplate.addContent(oEmployeeDetailsTemplate);  

    var oViewRepeater = new sap.suite.ui.commons.ViewRepeater("tilesViewReapeater", {  
        title: new sap.ui.commons.Title({text: "Employee View", level: sap.ui.commons.TitleLevel.H1}),  
        noData: new sap.ui.commons.TextView({text: "Sorry, no data available!"}),  

        showViews: false, // disable view selector  
        showSearchField: false,  

        //set view properties directly to the repeater  
        responsive: true,  
        itemMinWidth: 210,  
        numberOfRows: 5, // view property NumberOfTiles has legacy name here  
        rows: {  
            path: "/employees",  
            template: oTileTemplate  
        }  
    });  

    return oViewRepeater;
```

In HTML-Output is nothing rendered in the ViewRepeaters body ul-element.

I don't understand why the element is only rendered correctly when responsive is true? Has anybody an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you create a sample using JS Bin -> jsbin.com? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I don't see any model-binding being done, probably this is missing. (or going wrong)

Comment: Yes, there is. Within the 'rows' attribute a databinding object is declared using 'path' and 'template'.